# Refer to an endnote with the 'enotez' package points to the wrong note

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, endnotes

I've previously used the `\footref` command from the `footmisc` package to refer to an endnote. This has worked fine in combination with the `endnotes` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc,endnotes}
    \renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.\footnote{And here is an endnote.\label{foot.first}}\\
Here is more text.\footnote{And here is another endnote.\label{foot.second}}\\
Here is my final sentence.\footref{foot.first}\textsuperscript{,}\footref{foot.second}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I've now switched to the `enotez` package, and this no longer works properly. In the MWE below, the reference to the first endnote instead refers to the second endnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc,enotez}
    \renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.\footnote{And here is an endnote.\label{foot.first}}\\
Here is more text.\footnote{And here is another endnote.\label{foot.second}}\\
Here is my final sentence.\footref{foot.first}\textsuperscript{,}\footref{foot.second}
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make `enotez` refer to the correct endnote?

Comment: Put `\label` outside the footnote text: `\footnote{text}\label{x}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `enotez` the `\label` command should be outside the endnote text; see the final example in section 3.1.

You don't need `footmisc` as you can define a `\footref` command with `enotez` features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}

\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}
\newcommand{\footref}[1]{%
  \enotezwritemark{\enmarkstyle\ref{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text.\footnote{And here is an endnote.}\label{foot.first}\\
Here is more text.\footnote{And here is another endnote.}\label{foot.second}\\
Here is my final sentence.\footref{foot.first}\textsuperscript{,}\footref{foot.second}
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have several instances of multiple `\footref`, you can consider an abbreviated syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}

\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\footref}{m}
 {
  \sverre_footref:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_sverre_footrefs_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sverre_footref:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_sverre_footrefs_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_sverre_footrefs_seq
     { \enotezwritemark{\enmarkstyle\ref{##1}} }
   }
   \seq_use:Nn \l_sverre_footrefs_seq { \textsuperscript{,} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text.\footnote{And here is an endnote.}\label{foot.first}\\
Here is more text.\footnote{And here is another endnote.}\label{foot.second}\\
Here is my final sentence.\footref{foot.first,foot.second}
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or (since 2022), use `postnotes` instead, since `\label{...}` works in the typical/logical fashion, and the package has a further cross-referencing feature that you might like.  Quoting from the manual:

> Cross-referencing with postnotes works in a pretty standard way: set a label, make
> references to it. However, there are two ways to set a label to a note. One can either set
> a label with the `label` option of `\postnote`, or one can directly set it with the standard
> `\label` as part of the note’s content. They are both valid, but they are not equivalent,
> they have different meanings and, accordingly, behave differently. [¶]
> The label set with the `label` option is set at the place where `\postnote` is. The label
> set with `\label` in the note’s content, is just stored, and only gets expanded when this
> 13content gets to be typeset, at `\printpostnotes`. In short, the `label` option belongs to
> the “mark”, while the `\label` set in the content belongs to the “text”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc,postnotes}
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\postnote}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.\footnote{And here is an endnote.\label{foot.first}}\\
Here is more text.\footnote{And here is another endnote.\label{foot.second}}\\
Here is my final sentence.\footref{foot.first}\textsuperscript{,}\footref{foot.second}
\printpostnotes
\end{document}
```